# JSF2. Filter data in selectItems

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, filter, selectonemenu

I need in advice. I develop site with localized content in 2 languages. For that I use maps with key - lang and name smth - key. I have selectOneMenu with languageds and depends from this selectOneMenu lists with different data. I just reinit list getting value for selected lang. But data  in first language is mandatory. ANd on second lang not mandatory.

I think about some "filter" for selectOneMenu insteadof after eevery change lang again select data from database. Please give some good advice about this case and may be examples

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localized content on your site, you should be using resource bundles. Check out:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/resource-bundles-jsf-20

In my opinion, the filter should just be in the current language. I don't think it's worth having the filter use both languages...can't really see a use case for it as users tend to stick to one preferred language